# std::vector fails referencing the object to push in after code splitting

Tags: c++, std, stdvector

EDIT: aList was being referenced as a pointer in this version of my code, but not in my current version which still has the same problem.

I had this code perfectly working before trying to split it in an interface file and an implementation file. But when I splitted it, the compiler tells me I'm calling push_back() with incorrect parameters. So I understand it cannot reference the type of the object I'm pushing it, although it's the same (afaik, of course :D).

```
#ifndef _MYHEADER_HPP_
#define _MYHEADER_HPP_
class A{
public:
    std::string someString;
};

class B{
public:
    std::vector<A> aList;
public:
    void addA();
};

#endif /* _MYHEADER_HPP_ */

//implementation file

#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include "myheader.hpp"

void B::addA(){
    A a;
    a.someString = "Hola";
    // Here compiler says : Invalid arguments 'Candidates are: void push_back(const A &)' line 18 Semantic Error
    aList.push_back(a);
}
```

AFAIK, std::vector always do a copy of the object to push, and that copy gets stored into the vector, so I think it's not a problem of 'a' being stack allocated, am I right?

What I'm doing wrong?
Thanks.

Comment: Any chance those refer to different `A` definitions?

Comment: Unless I find that A class exists in the standard library, I think not :/

Comment: `aList` is not a pointer, so should be `aList.push_back(a);`

Comment: @hmjd you should post that as an answer.

Comment: @hmjd: That should be an answer.

Comment: can you post the current version of your code then?

Comment: Updated. I tried declaring pointer to vector of A, but it's the same. Also, if I do: std::cout << a.someString << std::endl; with this code in B::addA() I can see that the compiler can reference correctly to the contents of the a object, so it's very confusing...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, after more than 3 hours looking for the root of the problem, I found that Eclipse CDT IDE had a corrupted cache file about my code. So, compiling from command line was everything fine, I had to delete that cache file and then Eclipse reported no errors.